# Excel 2013 VBA Error

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit, excel-2013

I am getting following error.

```
Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems.
```

**VBA CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"
```

It works fine in Excel 2010.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Error I get is `Ret Variable Not defined`. Here's the rest of the code.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".mp3"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must be running this on a 64Bit version of Office whereas previously you were using a 32Bit version.

To convert 32Bit calls to 64Bit you generally have to add `PtrSafe` to the function and convert some of the data types from `Long` to `LongPtr` (which is merely a larger datatype (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251378.aspx)

So the converted function would be:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByRef pCaller As LongPtr, _
     ByVal szURL As String, _
     ByVal szFileName As String, _
     ByVal dwReserve As Long, _
     ByRef lpfnCB As LongPtr) _
As LongPtr
```

Edit: Note if you want to be able to use this on both 64Bit and 32Bit versions of Office you need to use a preprocessor If statement so Office knows which function to use.  Ie:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon".......
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon".......
#End If
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but I should've added rest of code too. Error I was getting before was fix thanks, but I am getting error that `Ret` variable not define.

Comment: No probs. You also need to convert the `Ret` variable from a `Long` to a `LongPtr` as this is the new return type for the function.  (if it is a global variable then use `Public` (or `Private` for just that module) instead of `Dim`)

Comment: Hi, sorry for I just got time. but I tried adding LongPtr and also tried Public but it didn't work. what should I do? thanks

Comment: I'd declare `Ret` within your module instead of globally. Is there any reason to declare it globally?  The only other thing is that instead of using `0`s for the `pCaller` and `lpfnCB` variables, you may need actual variables since they are passed `ByRef`.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251723.aspx)

> Complete error message: 
>   The code in this project must be updated for
>   use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and
>   then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute. All Declare Statements must
>   now include the PtrSafe keyword when running in 64-bit versions of
>   Microsoft Office. The PtrSafe keyword indicates a Declare statement is
>   safe to run in 64-bit versions of Microsoft Office. Adding the PtrSafe
>   keyword to a Declare statement only signifies the Declare statement
>   explicitly targets 64-bits, all data types within the statement that
>   need to store 64-bits (including return values and parameters) must
>   still be modified to hold 64-bit quantities using either LongLong for
>   64-bit integrals or LongPtr for pointers and handles.

Add the `PtrSafe` keyword.