# VBA in Excel to Download all PDFs from Webpage

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, download

I am needing to download all the PDFs from a webpage and save them into a folder. The PDFs on the webpage are downloaded via different links. Here is the webpage that the PDFs are located: NRCS Engineering Manuals and Handbooks | NRCS North Dakota. I have already created the folder location as shown below:

```
Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
'Macro Purpose: Check if a folder exists
On Error GoTo EarlyExit
If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True

EarlyExit:
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

'Creates file folder for saving imported precipitation data
'Used as Micro for "Make Destination Folder" Button

Sub Make_Folder()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(CurDir())

Range("u11").Select
Selection.ClearContents

' Opens windows explorer for creation of folder to save .pdf files
If Len(Dir(CurDir() & "\Stockwater PDFs", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir(CurDir() & "\Stockwater PDFs")

If FileFolderExists(CurDir() & "\Stockwater PDFs") Then
    MsgBox "Folder Created Sucessfully!!!"
Else
    MsgBox "Folder does not exist!"
End If

If FileFolderExists(CurDir() & "\Stockwater PDFs") Then
ActiveSheet.Range("u11").Value = "Stockwater PDFs folder made in the " & objFolder.Name
End If

End Sub
```

Once the files are downloaded from the website (the first part of the code below that I need help with) I would then list what files are located within the folder they were saved into (which I have already):

```
Sub GetWebPageDocs()

' Erases all listed files shown to be located in the CurDir()\Stockwater PDFs folder

Range("n17:n50").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("n16").Select

' Lists current files located in the CurDir()\Stockwater PDFs folder

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(CurDir() & "\Stockwater PDFs")
irow = 17
icolumn = 14
ActiveSheet.Range("N16").Value = "The files found in the " & objFolder.Name & " folder are:"

 'Loop through the Files collection
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ActiveSheet.Cells(irow, icolumn).Value = objFile.Name
    irow = irow + 1
    icolumn = icolumn

Next

 'Clean up!
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

If it would be easier to have all the desired PDFs located within a ZIP file that was a single link on the website then that may be the best option.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have tried the following but get a compile error on Dim xHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP

```
Dim sUrl As String
Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim hAnchor As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
Dim Ret As Long
Dim sPath As String
Dim i As Long

sPath = CurDir() & "\Stockwater PDFs"
sUrl = "http://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/nd/technical/engineering/?cid=stelprdb1269591"

'Get the directory listing
Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
xHttp.Open "GET", sUrl
xHttp.send

'Wait for the page to load
Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'Put the page in an HTML document
Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

'Loop through the hyperlinks on the directory listing
For i = 0 To hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Length - 1
    Set hAnchor = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(i)

    'test the pathname to see if it matches your pattern
    If hAnchor.pathname Like "*.pdf" Then
        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, sUrl & hAnchor.pathname, sPath & hAnchor.pathname, 0, 0)
        If Ret = 0 Then
            Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.pathname & " downloaded to " & sPath
        Else
            Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.pathname & " not downloaded"
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are seeking for help to code something that downloads PDF files from a certain website. Yet, I don't see any code which shows any attempt to download anything from any website. If I understood correctly, then the above code does not even seem to be related to the question at hand but merely the (possibly) necessary code "around" the actual task to handle the files once they have been downloaded. Yet, we are more interested to see your attempts to download the files. If I misunderstood the question altogether then please correct me.

Comment: @Ralph You are correct.  The code that I had listed would work around the "Download files" code.  I have tried the following but get a User-defined type not defined Compile Error on the Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Comment: @Ralph See edited post for the additional code.

Comment: Please also include the VBA code for the function `URLDownloadToFile` which you are referencing in your code. In respect to your above error: have you checked the references in your VBE for MSXML and MSHTML?

Comment: @Ralph 
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal sURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Comment: Are you running Excel 64bit or 32Bit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436646/excel-2013-vba-error Also, did you check the status of the URL before attempting to download the PDF?

Comment: @Ralph 64bit; I did load the references in VBA and now it runs everything but nothing gets downloaded.