# EXCEL VBA (URLDownloadToFile) Not working Due to Site not allowing IE11

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11, urlmon

I was wondering if anyone had an idea about how to get URLtoDownloadfile to work but get it to use Microsoft Edge as opposed to IE11. The websites trying to pull PDF's from now doesn't support IE11 so it just takes you to an error page. Plus I believe Microsoft are pulling it next year completely.

The reason for wanting to use this is because we want to save to a specific folder and file name based on logic within the excel document?

It was working perfectly up until one of the websites changed it support for IE11 so any help would be much appreciated.

Happy to paste in the code if that helps.

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59762080/11683?

Comment: Do you want to download PDF files in Edge? If so, I think you shouldn't use VBA to automate anymore. VBA is good at automating IE browser, but for other browsers, it's not a good option. We usually use [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) to automate Edge browser. You can try to use the newer technology to work with sites in Edge as [IE 11 will be retired on June 15, 2022](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/).